# Pandas check whether every word in a string exists in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a column of artist names and I'm trying to figure out whether the artist is using their real name. So I compiled a list of popular first or last names and put it into a set. I am now trying to go through all the words in each artist name and check whether they are in the set. I have split all the strings into lists (df["artist_name"].str.split()) but don't know how to iterate through all of the words in the list.

Comment: some code please

Comment: I have just imported the artist names and created the set of names:                                        df = pd.read_csv("artist_names")                                                                       names_df = pd.read_csv("names.txt", delimiter = "\n")
names_set = set(names_df["Names"].str.lower())

Comment: I mean code with data and you can edit the question to add code instead put them in comments!

Comment: Edit your question and add some code to it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single name stored in variable `name` and a list stored in variable `nameList`, you can check if the name is in the list simply by running `name in nameList`.

If you have a `fullName` variable, perhaps containing a first and a last name separated by a space, you can do the following:

```
any([name in nameList for name in fullName.split()])
```

This will return `True` if either the artist's first or last name is in the list you're comparing against. If you'd like to create a stricter comparison and require that both the first and last name be in the list, you can replace `any` with `all`.

The code below uses a pandas Series called `artistNames` and a list called `nameList` for comparison.

```
nameList = ['Fred','Steve','Susan','Jane','Robertson','Jones']
artistNames = pd.Series(['Steve Musicianson','NotARealName McRobotFace','Susan Artistsdottir','Fred Jones'])
anyRealName = artistNames.apply(lambda x: any(map(lambda y: y in nameList, x.split())))
allRealName = artistNames.apply(lambda x: all(map(lambda y: y in nameList, x.split())))
```

In this code, `anyRealName` will return

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
```

Whereas `allRealName` will return

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
```

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate through the artist names and check whether it is present in the real names list.

```
import pandas as pd

Panda = pd.read_csv("Artist_Details")

RealNames = [# This List will contain the real names of the artists.]

ArtistList = list(Panda['Artist'])

for Artist in ArtistList:
    if Artist not in RealNames:
        print(Artist)
```